# CS0103, 'InitializeComponent' doesn't exist in current context when working with other XAML pages

Tags: c#, xaml

I have been stuck on this for hours, the 'InitializeComponent' doesn't exist in current context.

```
public partial class CreateAccount : Window
{
    public CreateAccount()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
```

Here is my XAML code

```
<Window x:Class="HotelAccomadation.Interface.CreateAccount"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:HotelAccomadation.Interface"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    Title="CreateAccount" Height="450" Width="800"
    Background="AliceBlue"
    >
```

I have made sure the names are the same, what else should I do?

Comment: Have you tried cleaning and rebuilding the solution?

Comment: @Ibrennan208 yes I Have I still have the same error

Comment: Would it have anything to do with the first page and xaml.cs 'public Login()' not having any references?

Comment: There should be a `CreateAccount.g.cs` file somewhere in your `obj\`` directory - are you able to find it? (Tip: Use _VoidTools Everything_ to find it). Do you have any other projects in the solution and/or dependencies of this project with build errors?

Comment: @Dai No I Don't have that file should I have it? I have a xaml page and it has that file and works is there a way to generate it?

Comment: Same problem, but decades ago: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/015d0a72-85cd-445d-ac04-07c9e94a4304/no-window1gcs-file-generated-for-new-wpf-project?forum=wpf

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution to your issue is internal to your solution file, and isn't something immediately obvious. Follow these steps and you will be able to build your solution again.

1. Open your solution in Visual Studio
2. Right Click the project file (directly under the "Solution 'HotelAccommadation' (1 of 1 Project)" entry in the Solution Explorer
3. Select "Open folder in File Explorer"
4. Find the file "HotelAccommadation.csproj"
5. Edit this file so it looks like the code below I have attached. Be careful to match this exactly.
6. Clean your solution (from Solution Explorer)
7. Build your solution

Make sure you delete old classes referenced in this file, and make sure you add the new classes carefully.

```
<PropertyGroup>
    <OutputType>WinExe</OutputType>
    <TargetFramework>net6.0-windows</TargetFramework>
    <Nullable>enable</Nullable>
    <UseWPF>true</UseWPF>
    <EnableDefaultCompileItems>false</EnableDefaultCompileItems>
    <EnableDefaultPageItems>false</EnableDefaultPageItems>
</PropertyGroup>

<ItemGroup>
    <EmbeddedResource Remove="obj\**" />
    <None Remove="obj\**" />
</ItemGroup>

<ItemGroup>
    <None Remove="Interface\Booking.xaml" />
    <None Remove="Interface\CreateAccount.xaml" />
    <None Remove="Interface\Login.xaml" />
    <None Remove="Interface\Searchpg.xaml" />
    <None Remove="Interface\CreateAccommodation.xaml" />
</ItemGroup>

<ItemGroup>
    <Compile Include="DAL\AccessData.cs" />
    <Compile Include="Interface\Booking.xaml.cs" />
    <Compile Include="Interface\CreateAccommodation.xaml.cs" />
    <Compile Include="Interface\CreateAccount.xaml.cs" />
    <Compile Include="Interface\Searchpg.xaml.cs" />
    <Compile Include="Logic\createAccount.cs" />
    <Compile Include="Logic\LoginLg.cs" />
    <Compile Include="Interface\Login.xaml.cs" />
    <Compile Include="Logic\SearchLg.cs" />
    <Compile Include="Models\AccomMod.cs" />
    <Compile Include="Models\BookingMod.cs" />
    <Compile Include="Models\userModel.cs" />
</ItemGroup>

<ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="System.Data.SqlClient" Version="4.8.5" />
</ItemGroup>

<ItemGroup>
    <Page Include="Interface\Booking.xaml">
        <Generator>MSBuild:Compile</Generator>
    </Page>
    <Page Include="Interface\CreateAccount.xaml">
        <Generator>MSBuild:Compile</Generator>
    </Page>
    <Page Include="Interface\Login.xaml" />
    <Page Include="Interface\Searchpg.xaml">
        <Generator>MSBuild:Compile</Generator>
    </Page>
    <Page Include="Interface\CreateAccommodation.xaml">
        <Generator>MSBuild:Compile</Generator>
    </Page>
</ItemGroup>
```